# . file to execute a file in bash and > file to empty contents of file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Why does using `. file` in bash execute a file even if it's not and executable file? Is it because it uses the current bash session to run it so it works like typing `bash file`?

Also, along similar lines. I know that typing `> file` deletes the contents of a file. But why? I understand this sends the standard input to a file. But isn't the standard input the keyboard? So shouldn't I go to a new line in theory and type things? I don't understand.

Comment: `.` mean you are sourcing the file. eg like when you do C programming and you `include` something.  `>` with out anything infront, as same as you sending `null` to the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all `. file` does not execute the file, it sources it. That might sounds like a pedantic point but there is an important difference. When you execute a file, it is run in its own subshell; any variables defined in it, for example, will not be propagated to the parent session. To illustrate, consider this script (`foo.sh`) that simply sets a variable and then prints it:

```
foo="bar"
echo "In the script, foo is $foo"
```

Now, let's set the variable `foo` to something, then run that script and, once it is finished, `echo $foo`:

```
$ foo="baz" 
$ bash foo.sh 
In the script, foo is bar
$ echo $foo
baz
```

As you can see, `$foo` was set inside the script but that did not change the value of the variable in the parent shell. Contrast the above with what happens if we source the script instead:

```
$ . foo.sh 
In the script, foo is bar
$ echo $foo
bar
```

This time, because the script was sourced, the variable was also change in the parent shell.

---

The `> file` is simpler. The `>` operator opens a file (or creates it if it doesn't exist) for writing and immediately overwrites anything already in the file. Therefore, if you just run `> file` with nothing else, the `>` will empty the file if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid to ask two unrelated questions in the same post.

1: it doesn't exactly work like `bash file` because the latter run a new shell while `.` uses the same current shell. It works like `source file`.

2: The default standard input is indeed normally the keyboard but with running `> file`, there is no command to run. The shell just process the redirections then ends processing the (missing) command. What you describe would have been `cat > file`.